# Удалить массив С из памяти

Tags: c++

Полный текст задания: Даны два массива А и И одинакового размера N. Определить функцию, возвращающую новый массив С того же размера, каждый элемент которого равен сумме элементов массивов А и В с тем же индексом. Исходные массивы передаются в функцию в качестве параметров.

Я сделал это следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

int *printarray(int A[], int B[],const int N,int *C)
{
    C = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
    }
    return C;
}

int main()
{
    int N;
    setlocale(0, "rus");

    cout << "Введите размер массива: " << endl;
    cin >> N;

    cout << "Заполните числами массив А:" << endl;
    int* A = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        cin >> A[i];
    }

    cout << "Заполните числами массив В: " << endl;
    int* B = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        cin >> B[i];
    }
    int* C= new int;


    cout << "Новый массив С: " << endl;


    int *Y=printarray(A,B,N,C);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            cout << Y[i] << endl;
        }

    delete Y;
    delete A;
    delete B;
    delete C;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Программа работает, но преподаватель говорит, что массив С всё равно не удалён. Я уже по-разному пробовал его удалить, но всё бес толку. Помогите разобраться. заранее спасибо.

Comment: Он ожидает от вас `delete [] Y;` (и аналогично для остальных массивов) (но по сути, врет. Память вы освобождаете)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пишете:

```
 int* C= new int;
```

Дальше  этот обьект нигде не удаляется, так как ваш указатель после вызова функции указывает на массив. После этого вы не массивы удаляете, а только их первые элементы. Одним словом, нужно просто обьявить `С*` (можете инициализировать нулем и удалить весь массив. Я бы сказал, что этот указатель вовсе и не нужен, как и не нужен последный аргумент вашей функции. Ведь она всеравно возвращает указатель на массив:

```
int *printarray(int A[], int B[],const int N)
{
    int* C = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) 
        C[i] = A[i] + B[i];

    return C;
}
 //непонятно почему вы функцию так назвали...
int main() {
    //...
    int *Y=printarray(A,B,N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << Y[i] << endl;
    }

    delete []Y;
    delete []A;
    delete []B;
    //...
}
```